# How to differentiate $x^2-|x^3|$?

Tags: derivatives

How to differentiate $x^2-|x^3|$?

I tried breaking it into a piecewise function but I've been told this is not necessary.

How can I approach this in another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

so the equation becomes equivalent to 
$$x^2-\sqrt{x^6}$$

Comment: When I differentiate that way I get $2x-\frac{x^5}{\sqrt {x^6}}$ how can I go from here to saying $\frac{x^5}{\sqrt {x^6}}=|x^2|$ as far as I understand I can't say $x^5=\sqrt{x^{10}}$ as this doesn't hold for negative numbers, right?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD $$y'=2x-\frac{3x^5}{\sqrt{x^6}}=2x-\frac{3x^5}{|x^3|}$$

Comment: @Essam would that be equal to $2x-3x^2\cdot Sg^3(x)=2x-3x^2\cdot Sg(x)?$

Comment: How come? Isn't $Sg(x)= \frac{x}{|x|}$ thus $Sg^3(x)=\frac{x^3}{|x|^3}$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=x^2-|x^3|=\begin{cases}x^2-x^3~,~x\geq 0\\ x^2+x^3~,~x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

$$\implies f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x-3x^2=x(2-3x)~,~x\gt 0\\ 0~,~x=0\\ 2x+3x^2=x(2+3x)~,~x\lt 0\end{cases}$$

I think this is the simplest way to do it.

You can use piecewise functions. There is no problem with that. Any other approach mimics the same thing and will give you the exact same result.

Comment: Except $f'(0)=0$ does exist.

Comment: But the common value as $x \rightarrow 0 $ is $0$.

Comment: @aschepler, ah yes. Sorry for that. I thought of $f(x)=|x|$ and thought the same would apply here. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

We have the case of a composition of functions $g \circ f; g(x)=|x|, f(x)=x^3 $. The general result is that then $g \circ f $ is differentiable if (not of iff! ) g is differentiable at $f(x)$. But $g$ is differentiable everywhere except at 0 , so $g(f(x)$ may *at worst* not be differentiable at $0$, so that
the only possible problem with the derivative of  $|x^3|$ is at $0$, since $x^3$ is everywhere -differentiable and $|x|$ is differentiable everywhere but 0. But let of $0$, $3x^2 $ and $-3x^2$ both approach 0, so $x^2- |x^3|$ is everywhere differentiable.

EDIT: ultimately, the derivatives of $-x^3 , x^3$ are both everywhere continuous, and, in particular, are both continuous at $0$. By sequential continuity it follows that the limit t $0$ is $0$.

Comment: You seem to be using a theorem of sorts: If $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)= L ,$ then $f'(0) = L.$ Well, that's true, but is this what you intended? It might be easier just to compute $f'(0)$ from the definition.

Comment: Well, I am using that g is differentiable everywhere except at $x=0$, and so $g(f(x)$ is differentiable when $f(x) \ neq 0 $, an _possibl_ not at $x=0$. But the case at $x=0$  s clearly seen to be differentiable.

Comment: @zhw.: But I also want to justify that $g(f(x))$ is differentiable when $g$ is differentiable at $f(x)$ , to justify that $|x^3|$ is differentiable everywhere outside of _possibly_ $0$ an then showing that it is also differentiable at $0$..

Comment: Fine, but the route you chose to show the derivative exists at $0$ depends on the result I noted. It's a valid approach, but needs justification (it follows from the MVT). The easier route in this case, I think, is to just to go back to the definition of the derivative.

Comment: I think you can also use continuity, i.e., show that here both derivatives are continuous at $0$. But the MVT would show it too. I will edit to rigorize.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

We have $f(0) = 0$ and  $f(x) = x^2(1 - |x|)$, as $|x|^3 = |x|x^2$.

Hence the derivative at zero,

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2(1-|x|)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} x(1-|x|) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use is :

$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} \vert x \vert = \frac{\vert x \vert}{x}$$

So with the chain rule you get:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} x^2 - \vert x^3 \vert
&= 2x -  \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} \vert x^3 \vert \\
&= 2x -  \frac{\vert x^3 \vert}{x^3} \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} x^3 \\
&= 2x -  \frac{\vert x^3 \vert}{x^3} 2x^2 \\
&= 2x -  \frac 2x \vert x^3 \vert \\
\end{align}$$